# How to create Bitmap from file on server - parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, bitmap, system.drawing

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(imageName, "http://panonest.com", "");
var imgSrc=req.MapPath("~/view/vacantapredeal/vacantapredeal.jpg");
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(imgSrc);
```

How should I do this? I get a parameter is not valid exception, which is thrown by the `Bitmap` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is another way to do it:

```
  WebClient MyWebClient = new WebClient();
    byte[] BytesImage = MyWebClient.DownloadData("http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png");
    System.IO.MemoryStream iStream= new System.IO.MemoryStream(BytesImage);
    System.Drawing.Bitmap b = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(iStream);
```

Good luck!

Comment: I like the downloaddata ideea. Just a question: If my image and the code are on the same server would this require more time, or is equivalent to Kelsey's answer?

Comment: If your images are on your server I would go wirh Kelsey's answer since it does not make any type of HTTP Request.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just loading the image from your local server you can do it easily using `System.Drawing.Image`:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp =
    new System.Drawing.Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(
        MapPath("~/view/vacantapredeal/vacantapredeal.jpg")));
```

Answer (score -1):

If this is an image on a remote server, then according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw.aspx), you need to do something like:

```
System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://panonest.com" + imageName);
System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

Bitmap bitmap2 = new Bitmap(responseStream);
bitmap2.Save("~/view/vacantapredeal/vacantapredeal.jpg");
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain what's wrong with my answer?